# I ran npm install directly on my ssh and now git ci/cd is not updating anymore

Tags: git, amazon-ec2, deployment

Last night I merged a pull request in Git, on a repo that has script to continually deploy to a machine, and then ran

```shell
npm i react lottie -force
```

directly on the machine.

After checking the website, the machine updated the files from the repo.
2 minutes later I decided to revert this commit, and I did so from GitKraken. The repo was reverted to the commit, but the machine was not.

Since then, I see the Git actions pass validation like always, but I check the files on the machine and they won't update anymore like before last night.

I can't think of any reason which caused the ci/cd to stop syncing..
How can I set ci/cd to sync again?